# How can I change the background color for the the Eclipse 3.5 editor?

Tags: eclipse

I am checking in Windows + General+Editors+Editors/Appearance. I could not find the correct property. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Window Preferences -> General+Editors+TextEditors+Background Color
```